# /bin/sh: rm: command not found

Tags: applescript, bash, error, command-line

I have problems with some applications that use AppleScript `shell script` feature. For example, Growl's uninstall scripts shows an error:

```
error "/bin/sh: rm: command not found" number 127
```

The source of the script is

```
display dialog (localized string "title")
if button returned of result = "OK" then
    try
        quit application id "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp"
    end try
    try
        quit application id "com.Growl.MenuExtra"
    end try
    do shell script "rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/Growl.prefPane ~/Library/PreferencePanes/Growl.prefPane" with administrator privileges
    display dialog (localized string "succeeded") buttons {localized string "OK"} default button 1
end if
```

I've added `echo $PATH > /omg.txt &&` to the command to see what's the search path for rm. But it has a weird value:

```
$ cat /omg.txt 
â
```

What can I do? I don't understand what's going on. When I just run `sudo /bin/sh` in Terminal, the environment is just fine!

Now, I know that to uninstall Growl I can just run the command it tries to run in the Terminal. But it won't solve this problem, just postpone it until another application fails with the same error (it happened before).

Answer (score 5):

According to [Apple's official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2065/_index.html), it is by design that shell scripts invoked from AppleScript's `do shell script` action do **not** inherit the `$PATH` variable from your login shell's environment.

Accordingly, Apple instructs users to use full paths to commands when invoking shell scripts from AppleScript rather than relying on the $PATH variable in the environment.

In the script in your example, you could replace `rm` with `/bin/rm`

According to the aforelinked documentation, this is the intended, documented behavior; a script that expects the environment's `$PATH` to be set for `do shell script` commands is a script with a bug.

That said, if you absolutely need to use relative paths and use $PATH to complete them, you could prefix any shell script called by `do shell script` with the command `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin;`

Comment: this won't work for all the others scripts :(

Comment: Scripts that rely on the $PATH variable to be set are, according to the documentation, buggy. See revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

hotfix = give the location of `rm` command:

```
do shell script "/bin/rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/Growl.prefPane ~/Library/PreferencePanes/Growl.prefPane" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: it won't solve the problem once and for all :(

Answer (score 1):

You could actually use Daniel's suggestion of exporting paths, but save it as a script unto itself (call it "dss" for do shell script, or something) and place it in *usr/local/bin*. That way the next time you need to run an *osa* script like the Growl uninstall, you can call your script from the command line to set $PATH, run the *osa* job, and then be finished. 
Not a permanent solution, but highly workable.

Comment: Will the osa pass its inherited environment on to scripts it spawns with `do shell script`?

Comment: I believe so, at least if the script is using subroutines. Subroutines of a parent script will inherit the environment variables for that process.